# Не понимаю как правильно определить <configSection> в App.config (C# WinForms)

Tags: c#, .net, xml, configuration

App.config:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name = "PokerClients" type = "WindowsFormsApplication1.PokerClientsConfig"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings>
    <PokerClients>
       <PokerClient key="PokerStars" name ="Poker stars" wndclass = "PokerStarsTableFrameClass"/>
       <PokerClient key="poker" name ="888 Poker" wndclass = "Poker888StarsTableFrameClass"/>
     </PokerClients>
  </appSettings>
</configuration>
```

---

вот реализация (взял [от сюда](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1316058/how-to-create-custom-config-section-in-app-config)) .

```
namespace WindowsFormsApplication1 //"модуль формы" 
{
public class PokerClient : ConfigurationElement
{

    [ConfigurationProperty("key", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Key
    {
        get
        {
            return this["key"] as string;
        }
    }
    [ConfigurationProperty("name", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Name
    {
        get
        {
            return this["name"] as string;
        }
    }
    [ConfigurationProperty("wndclass", IsRequired = true)]
    public string Wndclass
    {
        get
        {
            return this["wndclass"] as string;
        }
    }

}

public class PokerClients : ConfigurationElementCollection
{
    public PokerClient this[int index]
    {
        get
        {
            return base.BaseGet(index) as PokerClient;
        }
        set
        {
            if (base.BaseGet(index) != null)
            {
                base.BaseRemoveAt(index);
            }
            this.BaseAdd(index, value);
        }
    }

    public new PokerClient this[string responseString]
    {
        get { return (PokerClient)BaseGet(responseString); }
        set
        {
            if (BaseGet(responseString) != null)
            {
                BaseRemoveAt(BaseIndexOf(BaseGet(responseString)));
            }
            BaseAdd(value);
        }
    }

    protected override System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement CreateNewElement()
    {
        return new PokerClient();
    }

    protected override object GetElementKey(System.Configuration.ConfigurationElement element)
    {
        return ((PokerClient)element).Name;
    }
}

public class PokerClientsConfig : ConfigurationSection
{
  public static PokerClientsConfig GetConfig()
    {
        return (PokerClientsConfig)ConfigurationManager.GetSection("PokerClients") ?? new PokerClientsConfig();
    }

  [System.Configuration.ConfigurationProperty("PokerClients")]
  [ConfigurationCollection(typeof(PokerClients), AddItemName = "PokerClient")]
  public PokerClients PokerClients
  {
      get
      {
          object o = this["PokerClients"];
          return o as PokerClients;
      }
  }
}
```

}

---

при попытке получить секцию (метод GetConfig)

```
var Config = PokerClientsConfig.GetConfig();
```

возникает ошибка:

> Необработанное исключение типа
>   "System.Configuration.ConfigurationErrorsException" в
>   System.Configuration.dll
>
> Дополнительные сведения: Ошибка при создании обработчика раздела
>   конфигурации для PokerClients: Не удалось загрузить тип
>   "WindowsFormsApplication1.PokerClientsConfig" из сборки
>   "System.Configuration, Version=4.0.0.0, Culture=neutral,
>   PublicKeyToken=b03f5f7f11d50a3a"

Что в моем случае нужно писать в свойстве type? Я понял что там прописывается **[namespace].[класс обработчик]** а потом в большинстве случаев тот же **namespace** (так тоже пробовал), но тоже "не удается загрузить файл или сборку".

Comment: А разве секция PokerClients в файле конфигурации должна быть внутри appSettings? Вы же её описали как самостоятельную секцию.

Comment: Да, может это и верно. Но проблему это не решает - framework не может загрузить тип "WindowsFormsApplication1.PokerClientsConfig" или не видит его. Что мне там нужно указать?

Answer (score 1):

Вам следует указать квалифицированное сборкой имя типа, чтобы система конфигурации могла его найти среди всех сборок:

```
  <configSections>
    <section name = "PokerClientSection" type = "WindowsFormsApplication1.PokerClientsConfig, WindowsFormsApplication1"/>
  </configSections>
```

Здесь я предполагаю, что имя вашей сборки совпадает с именем пространства имен, т.е. сборка должна лежать в файле `WindowsFormsApplication1.exe` или `WindowsFormsApplication1.dll`. Если это не так - впишите нужное имя.

Comment: Пробовал указать:

An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for PokerClientSection: Could not load file or assembly 'WindowsFormsApplication1' or one of its dependencies. The system cannot find the file specified.

Comment: @СергейSer а как у вас сборка называется?

Comment: Да, получилось. Имя моей сборки не совпадает с именем пространства имен, в котором находится класс-обработчик. Я неправильно думал, что "сборка" и пространство имен - одно и то же.

Answer (score -1):

У вас имя секции и имя класса-коллекции совпадает (`PokerClients`). Попробуйте изменить файл конфигурации следующим образом:

```
<configuration>
  <configSections>
    <section name = "PokerClientSection" type = "WindowsFormsApplication1.PokerClientsConfig"/>
  </configSections>
  <startup>
    <supportedRuntime version="v4.0" sku=".NETFramework,Version=v4.5" />
  </startup>
  <appSettings></appSettings>
  <PokerClientSection>
    <PokerClients>
       <PokerClient key="PokerStars" name ="Poker stars" wndclass = "PokerStarsTableFrameClass"/>
       <PokerClient key="poker" name ="888 Poker" wndclass = "Poker888StarsTableFrameClass"/>
    </PokerClients>
  </PokerClientSection>
</configuration>
```

должно сработать

Comment: Поменял файл как Вы сказали,пробую даже так 
  
    var section = ConfigurationManager.GetSection("PokerClientSection");            
выскакивает ConfigurationErrorException:                                                 An error occurred creating the configuration section handler for PokerClientSection: Could not load type 'WindowsFormsApplication1.PokerClientsConfig' from assembly